# How fill a plot to a given y0 value

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I'm using Plotly in R and I want to create a plot like this:
[image: Fill to y0]

But when trying with fill = "tozeroy" the plot looks like this:
[image: fill tozeroy]

Ignoring the value of y0

So, I want to fill the area from the lines to y0 value, instead to absolute zero.

A code example:

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)

x <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017/01/01"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), by = 1)
y1 <- rnorm(365, 100, 10)
y2 <- rnorm(365, 100, 10)

dat <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

plot_ly(dat, x = ~x, y = ~y1, mode = "lines", type = "scatter", fill = "tozeroy", y0 = 80, name = "y1") %>%
add_trace(dat, x = ~x, y = ~y2, fill = 'tozeroy', y0 = 80, name = "y2")%>%
layout(xaxis = list(title = ""), yaxis = list(title = ""))
```

produces:
[image: CodeExample output]

Ignoring the `y0 = 80` parameter.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. This will make it much easier for others to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want the range to begin in `y0`.
To that end, you have to change the `yaxis`' range in the `layout`.

This should suffice:

```
library(plotly)
library(magrittr)
set.seed(19)

x <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017/01/01"), as.Date("2017/12/31"), by = 1)
y1 <- rnorm(365, 100, 10)
y2 <- rnorm(365, 100, 10)

y0 <- 80
ymax <- max(y1,y2)

dat <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

plot_ly(dat, x = ~x, y = ~y1, mode = "lines", type = "scatter", fill = "tozeroy", y0 = 80, name = "y1") %>%
  add_trace(dat, x = ~x, y = ~y2, fill = 'tozeroy',  name = "y2")%>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = ""), yaxis = list(range = c(y0, ymax),title = ""))
```

The range options in `plotly` are explained [here](https://plot.ly/r/axes/#rangemode)